# Unix System Call in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, unix, system-calls

Is it possible to make system call in Objective-C?

I have the following code:

```
if (!system("ls -l")) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully executed"); 
} else {
      NSLog(@"Error while executing the command"); 
}
```

How to get the output?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a perfect candidate for using [`-[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) instead of wrapping a built-in shell function and parsing the output. For general-purpose commands where you need the output — and where there is no equivalent functionality "for free" in Cocoa (it just takes time to learn the available APIs) — [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) is generally a far better alternative than `system()`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html). If you just need the results of `ls`, there are more appropriate filesystem wrappers in Cocoa.

Answer (score 4):

If you like to do it the C way you can use `popen`. This can be used to read the output also. But the answers about using Objective-C solutions are probably the better ones.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C does not prevent a program to invoque `system()` or any of its equivalents.

CocoaTouch does.